# what does "?" mean in Android styles.xml files mean?

Tags: android, xml, styles

in Android Framework source code  **~/core/res/res/values/styles.xml**

there's one line:

```
    <item name="android:textColor">?textColorPrimaryInverse</item>
```

Could anyone tell me:

1. What does `"?textColorPrimaryInverse"` mean?
2. Where is `"textColorPrimaryInverse"` referenced ?

Comment: Please check this link. So, you can get the idea about the textColorPrimaryInverse: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#textColorPrimaryInverse

Comment: oh...come on ... don't down vote me...

Comment: "Must be a reference to another resource, in the form "@[+][package:]type:name" or to a theme attribute in the form "?[package:][type:]name"." this is the answer to the question, thanks ~

Comment: You are welcome bro!! That's the reason i have given you a link for better understanding.

Comment: hey! Post your answer, so I can give you some points. @DeepMehta

Comment: Hey, I have posted that comment as an answer. Please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this link. So, you can get the idea about the textColorPrimaryInverse: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#textColorPrimaryInverse